# Exclude specific Facebook people from the friend suggestion feature

Tags: facebook

I have a few Facebook friends whom I don't want the automatic friend suggester ("People You May Know") to base the suggestions on.

Is it possible to stop Facebook from suggesting friends based on a specified set of friends?

Comment: This would be a nice feature, you could filter out those you add for games versus those you actually know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Here's their info page about the 'Friend Suggester' feature: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=15325

I'm not sure how much logic they coded that feature with, but if you repeatedly click the 'X' on people that it suggests based on your "game" friends, maybe it will eventually suggest less of them?